# Magento 2 Multi website for "product_websites" column in CSV file

Tags: magento2, store-view, multi-website

I'm using multi website. When I upload products using CSV I set "product_websites" column as "default" instead of "sports". Again I make changes in "product_websites" column as "sports" and tried to Add/Update, products are set in both "default" & "sports" website. How to set my new products only in "sports" website.

I don't want to replace the products..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to Magento admin panel **Store->All Stores**. Check the website code, store code, and store view from where you have exported the products CSV. Now, you can replicate the same values into the Magento site you want to import the products. Once done correctly. The error will get resolved.
By default as per magento 2.3.3 the values are :
Main Website
(Code: base)    Main Website Store
(Code: main_website_store)  Default Store View
(Code: default)

[image: Navigate to Stores->All Stores]
[image: All Stores Settings]